# Не могу передать переменные между страницами PHP. Как решить проблему?

Tags: php

Не могу передать переменные между страницами PHP.

Делаю так:

```
//Страница 1
session_start();
  $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
  $_SESSION["user_mail"] = $user_info['email'];
  $_COOKIE["user_id"] = $user_id;
  $_COOKIE["user_mail"] = $user_info['email'];

//Страница 2
session_start();
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $user_mail = $_SESSION["user_mail"];
    $user_id = $_COOKIE["user_id"];
    $user_mail = $_COOKIE["user_mail"];
```

Но на второй странице Сессия вообще не работает, а в Куки нет моих переменных. Почему так и как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, [починим кукисы](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php):

> `setcookie(...)`

вместо

> `$_COOKIE["user_id"] = $user_id;`

Если не помогло, то посмотри диспетчером хрома на вторую страницу - кукисы вообще с `PHPSESSID` отсылаются в заголовках или нет?

Comment: посылаются, но моих кук там нет ;(

Comment: поищи в php.ini что-нибудь связанное с cookie или session.
А если первую страницу обновлять и устанавливать на ней куки через setcookie и на ней же делать var_dump($_COOKIE) то что происходит при паре обновлений ?